# Source for Taanis Esther as a tikkun for the Eitz Hadaas?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, fast-days, trees, gan-eden

In [this article](http://www.yated.com/eyes-on-the-gauge.3-594-3-.html) the author asserts in the name of Rav Chaim Vital that

> The three-day fast that Mordechai and Esther ordered for the Jewish people, says Rav Chaim Vital, was a tikkun for the original sin of eating from the Eitz Hadaas.

I would like to know where this statement is located in the writings of R' Vital.

Answer (score 3):

[Bnei Yissaschar - Adar 7:9](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4683&st=&pgnum=330&hilite=) mentions it in the name of [Medrash Eliyahu - Section beginning Yalkut](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30790&st=&pgnum=140&hilite=) in the name of Rabbi Chaim Vital.

This is also mentioned in the Shlah Hakodosh - Derush L'Parshas Zachor.

> אסתר גזרה תענית תקנה חטא אכילה. וגם בסעודה שעשתה החרידה לישראל וגרמה
>   לתשובה תקנה חטא סעודת אחשורוש. וענין אכילה ועבודה זרה ענין נחש וסמאל,
>   אכילה כמו אכילת פרי עץ הדעת, עבודה זרה היתה שמוציאה דיבה גם כן שם,
>   שהוציאה הנחש מן העץ הזה אכל וברא את העולם, וזהו כפירה בחידוש העולם, כי
>   החידוש מורה על מציאות הש"י כמו שכתבתי במקום אחר. הרי שמבצבץ הנחש בהמן,
>   וזה כוונת רז"ל המן מן התורה מנין, שנאמר, המן העץ. ונתעורר אז עבודה זרה
>   שעשה עצמו המן להשתחוות לו לעורר אנדרטי דנבוכדנצר: